# Is it possible to commit the pre-commit hooks?

Tags: git

We set up a pre-commit hook for our Python project. The `pre-commit` sits in the `.git` folder which is untracked (for good reason).

But it's quite common for someone new to clone a repo and forget to get up the commit hook. Is it possible to automate this? E.g. by having the commit hook tracked by git? Or via some other mechanism e.g. when `git clone` is called the hook is automatically set up.

For example, adding the `!.git/hooks/pre-commmit` to `.gitignore` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Tell people to use a script to do the clone. Make the script copy (or symlink) the correct hook into place.

Comment: That seems the logical conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but not recommended.

When a repository is initialized, it copies hooks from [git template](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory). We can create a `post-checkout` in the template. Here's a sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

gitworktree=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
if [[ -f ${gitworktree}/pre-commit ]];then
    echo deploy pre-commit
    cp -v ${gitworktree}/pre-commit ${gitworktree}/.git/hooks/pre-commit
    chmod a+x ${gitworktree}/.git/hooks/pre-commit
fi
```

After `git clone` without `-n`, the `post-checkout` is copied to the new repository's `.git/hooks` automatically. And then the code is checked out and it invokes `post-checkout`. If `pre-commit` exists in the new repository, it's copied to `.git/hooks`. This is just a draft plan. There might be some issues in a real case. For example, how can we deal with the `pre-commit` which already exists in the template? Is it necessary to check if the `pre-commit` is a committed one? What if there are vicious codes in `pre-commit`?

As other answers say, it's not a good idea. Don't do it in production envirionment.

Comment: "*…copies hooks from git template.*" So first one needs to distribute the template directory and then users must remember to clone using `git clone --template` or `git clone --hooks-path`?

Comment: @phd There's a default template path. One needs to install the hook in the path. It's used if the template is not specified.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible.

(Funny that this answers your question, I'd suggest to rename it as "how to commit the pre-commit hook")

I'm not sure how to do this in python project that don't have build-system. You could add some lines to the readme file.

What we are doing in dotnet and android project: we add to our project buid a stage that would set-up a hook. And it's highly likely that the developer would build the project at least once before committing.

We have directory `/git_hooks` and script that copies files from it:

```xml
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="Install Git Hooks" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)/git_hooks/pre-commit" 
          DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)/.git/hooks" 
          ContinueOnError="true" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

or

```
buildscript {
   //.....
    copy {
        from "./git_hooks"
        into "./.git/hooks"
        fileMode 0777
    }
}
```

on Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this automatically because hooks can run arbitrary code and any mechanism to automatically set up hooks would be a security vulnerability, since it would let the owners of the repository execute arbitrary code on a developer machine.

However, you may wish to check them into a place in the repository and then set up a standard script (such as [the kind GitHub uses](https://github.com/github/scripts-to-rule-them-all)) which installs hooks and prepares the repository for use.

I would, however, encourage you to read the [Git FAQ entry about `pre-commit` hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks).  It points out that they are there to help developers and not as an effective control, since they can be easily bypassed without notice.  In addition, many developers who use a workflow with frequent squashing and rebasing (of which I am one) find `pre-commit` hooks to be an irritating impediment to their standard workflow since many temporary commits are created and destroyed.  You are therefore better off using a CI system to verify things like tests and code style and make hooks an opt-in for developers if they'd like to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://pre-commit.com/

You can create a separate repository with your hooks and use it in your projects. Usage is configured via YAML-files.

Comment: This is probably the easiest. But you still need to provide instructions on activating the hooks. Alternatively use husky: https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/

Answer (score 0):

Its not directly possible to commit as .git folder is ignored by default and evening unignoring won't work. But there is always a work around.

We have stored out `pre-commit` hook in separate folder `git/hooks` within our repo, as shown below

```
git
└── hooks
    └── pre-commit
```

and then we have script `install-git-hooks.sh` with very simple copy command.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r git/hooks/ .git/hooks/
```

So, on dev machines just run that script and we are good.